# how to receive responses from the iso8583 in wso2

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb, wso2-api-manager, iso8583

I already made the flow and all the works with the flow. I'm using socket test to test it and using postman as the api caller.  But when I send the respond from the socket test I can't receive the responses to the postman. Any solutions for that?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<api context="/sendiso" name="SendisoTestAPI" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <resource methods="POST">
        <inSequence>
            <log>
                <property name="status" value="Sending_an_ISO8583_Messsage"/>
            </log>
            <iso8583.init>
                <serverHost>localhost</serverHost>
                <serverPort>5010</serverPort>
            </iso8583.init>
            <iso8583.sendMessage/>
            <respond/>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence/>
        <faultSequence/>
    </resource>
</api>
```

I use that source but I had no responses from the socket test. Any solutions for this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

This could be probably due to your test backend does not send a response. The test server needs to generate responses by changing the relevant response fields and sending the responses back to the connector.

You can find a sample code here for a java ISO8583 Test Server[1]. Please verify whether your test backend server responds.

[1] https://github.com/wso2-docs/CONNECTORS/tree/master/ISO8583/ISO8583TestServer